# Slider Revolution carousel override single slide transition type

Tags: javascript, jquery, revolution-slider

I'm using the Slider Revolution jQuery plugin (not WP plugin) and set `sliderType:"carousel"` on my slider.

I want to use a fade transition when restarting the slider, when it goes from the last slide to the 1st again. All transitions

I tried setting `data-transition="fade"` on slide 1, but that didn't work.

How can this be accomplished? Thanks! Here's my code:

```
revapi1078 = tpj("#rev_slider_1078_1").show().revolution({
                sliderType:"carousel",
                carousel: {
                    maxVisibleItems: 1,
                    infinity: 'on',
                    stretch: 'on',
                    fadeout: 'off',          
                },
                horizontal_align: 'left',
                jsFileLocation:"revolution/js/",
                sliderLayout:"auto",
                minHeight: '1496',
                dottedOverlay:"none",
                delay:9000,
                navigation: {
                    keyboardNavigation:"off",
                    keyboard_direction: "horizontal",
                    mouseScrollNavigation:"off",
                    mouseScrollReverse:"default",
                    onHoverStop:"off",
                    touch:{
                        touchenabled:"off",
                    },
                    arrows: {
                        style:"hesperiden",
                        enable:true,
                        hide_onmobile:false,
                        hide_under:600,
                        hide_onleave:false,
                        hide_delay:200,
                        hide_delay_mobile:1200,
                        left: {
                            h_align:"left",
                            v_align:"center",
                            h_offset:30,
                            v_offset:0
                        },
                        right: {
                            h_align:"right",
                            v_align:"center",
                            h_offset:30,
                            v_offset:0
                        }
                    },

                },
                viewPort: {
                    enable:true,
                    outof:"pause",
                    visible_area:"80%",
                    presize:false
                },
                responsiveLevels:[1240,1024,778,480],
                visibilityLevels:[1240,1024,778,480],
                gridwidth: 2048,
                gridheight:[600,600,500,400],
                lazyType:"none",
                shadow:0,
                spinner:"off",
                stopLoop: 'off',
                stopAfterLoops: -1,
                stopAtSlide: -1,
                shuffle:"off",
                autoHeight:"off",
                hideThumbsOnMobile:"off",
                hideSliderAtLimit:0,
                hideCaptionAtLimit:0,
                hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,
                debugMode:false,
                fallbacks: {
                    simplifyAll:"off",
                    nextSlideOnWindowFocus:"off",
                    disableFocusListener:false,
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please add your current code to the question.